# SharePoint Online javascript script injection in onedrive

Tags: sharepoint-online

How to do onedrive branding in sharepoint online.
Seems application page is there (`/_layouts/15/onedrive.aspx`) so any way to inject JavaScript/Brand it?

Comment: @AsadRefai - REALLY not a good idea. Even with SharePoint this is not recommended. ODfB is still changing rapidly, having a custom master page is likely to cause you significant pain and management costs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is actually possible. I'm afraid I've not tried it and would personally check it out with Microsoft themselves.

However, there are recommended ways of injecting data into SharePoint pages and it is possible that they may work with ODfB. Check out the `UserCustomActions` class from the Microsoft.SharePoint.Client namespace. You can call that from PowerShell CSOM to add a permanent injection to all pages on a site - there is a partial example in the [comments of this blog post](http://www.timferro.com/wordpress/archives/841/comment-page-1).

But I would bear in mind that Microsoft seem intent on making ODfB look like consumer OneDrive at present so I would expect that any customisations you make now would break fairly rapidly over the next 12 months.